# How to add jars dynamically with jython embedded in Tomcat app?

Tags: tomcat, classpath, jython

I want to let the users of my app, which is in turn an app container (app contains subapps), add java jars to their jython path.

I let the subapp managers write thir own extensions in jython, but some of the functionality they want to add needs additional jars. For example, if they want to check a svn repo, they need the svn access jars, which I would rather not copy to /WEB-INF/lib, but rather to /subapps/appX/lib.

While I can add a class directory structure to sys.path, it seems that I can't add a jar. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is funny. It did not work from the command line, but it does when trying from tomcat. Might there be a delay in caching or so?

In the command line, if I try a non-existant import, the cache manager shows the new package found for the newly added jar. And *then* it works.